# Push Notification From Android Phone to Android Tablet

Tags: notifications, push-notification, android, xoom

I recently got the Xoom, for some reason I thought you could SMS message on it :-S

Does anyone know a way that from my android phone I can push a notification to my tablet to tell me I have a message or even if someone is calling.

Basically I want to mainly use my tablet and keep my phone in my laptop bag but be notified if I get a message.

Any help will be greatly received.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to develop an application which can talk to another instance of the same application over Bluetooth (or Wi-fi). The application running on the phone can listen for the broadcast of an incoming SMS, and send the info to the paired device (Xoom) where it will throw a Notification.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping there would be an app to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested it seems HTC have solved this.

HTC have an online service for sense found at: https://www.htcsense.com

From here once you have linked your Google account you can read and send text messages pushing them through your phone.

This allows me to use the browser on my Xoom tablet to send SMS messages.